# Why can't I find in Selenium an element by id when searching for multiple elements

Tags: java, html, selenium

I have a web page with one element that has the unique id "SomeID"

When searching for single element with the method "findElement" it finds the element.

`WebElement element = webDriver.findElement(By.id(SomeID))`

When using the method for searching multiple elements, I'm getting back an array of 0

```
List<WebElement> elements = webDriver.findElements(By.id(SomeID));
```

I don't understand why it doesn't find the element with "findElements".

Is it because "id" should be unique per container?

Will "findElements" work on other types of searches (xpath, etc.)?

Thanks

Comment: Your count should be 1 in this case. You may provide us the code.

Comment: id attribute should be unique. if you have multiple elements that need standard functionality or characteristics you should consider creating a class instead.

Answer (score 1):

The locator `By.id` will always return a single element, even if there's more than one. It's probably because the W3C standard specifies that an `id` has to be unique, but it's not enforced by the browser.

To get all the elements with same id, use `By.cssSelector` with a condition on the `id` attribute:

```
List<WebElement> elements = webDriver.findElements(By.cssSelector("[id='some-id']"));
```

Note that you are probably facing a timing issue. In this case use a waiter:

```
List<WebElement> elements = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
  .until(EC.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.cssSelector("[id='some-id']")));
```